# Call BIOS with return

Tags: c, assembly, x86-16

I am creating a bootload, I want to init graphic but when I try to get vbeInfoBlock, there are no return:
my code is:

```
#include "boot.h"
#include <stddef.h>
/*jump boot code entry*/
__asm__("jmpl $0x0000, $main\n");

/* user defined function to print series of characters terminated by null character */
void main() {
     /* calling the printString function passing string as an argument */
     printString("trump !!");
     printString("jouer à LOL");
     initGraphic();
     while(1);
} 
void initGraphic(){
     struct vbeInfoBlock* test;
     vbe_get_descr(test);
     printString(test->version);
     asm("movb $0, %ah");
     asm volatile("mov %0, %%ax":: "i"(0x4F02));
     asm volatile("mov %0, %%bx":: "i"(0x011B));
     //asm volatile("int %0" :: "i"(16)); 
}
void vbe_get_descr (vbeInfoBlock* descr) {
     /* sanity checks */
     if (!descr){
        return;
     }     
     /* call BIOS */
     asm volatile("mov %0, %%ax":: "i"(0x4F00));
     asm volatile("mov %0, %%es":: "Q"((unsigned int)&descr));
     asm volatile("mov %0, %%di":: "e"((unsigned int)sizeof(descr)));
     asm volatile("int %0" :: "i"(16)); 
}
```

vbeInfoBlock:

```
    typedef struct vbeInfoBlock {
        uint8_t  signature[4];     // “VESA”
        uint16_t version;          // Either 0x0200 (VBE 2.0) or 0x0300 (VBE 3.0)
        uint32_t oemString;        // Far pointer to OEM name
        uint8_t  capabilities[4];  // capabilities
        uint32_t videoModesPtr;    // Far pointer to video mode list
        uint16_t totalMemory;      // Memory size in 64K blocks
        uint16_t oemSoftwareRev;
        uint32_t oemVenderNamePtr;
        uint32_t oemProductNamePtr;
        uint32_t oemProductRevPtr;
        uint8_t  reserved [222];
        uint8_t  oemData [256];
}vbeInfoBlock;
```

With the printstring I just see if it is nul variable and on my screen I can see it is null variable. I wonder have a return value by example in version.

Comment: `es:di` needs to be a pointer to the buffer. You set `es` to the offset instead of the segment, and `di` to the size instead of the offset. PS: I believe you have already been told that separate asm statements are not guaranteed to work. You should put the stuff you want to keep together into a single asm block.

Comment: How can I do with the code because I  change segment there is an contrainst error

Comment: @KonectTeam: The compiler probably expects that SS = DS = ES (and everything will probably break if this isn't true); so you probably don't need to load ES in the first place. You will need memory for the BIOS to copy the data into though - maybe use `struct vbeInfoBlock test;` and `vbe_get_descr(&test);`.